# Solspace Rating - {if rating_comment_no_results} is never true!

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating, no-results

I'm using Rating 3.2.3 and EE 2.7.2.

In my template, the tag `{if rating_comment_no_results}` never returns true and never displays its content, even when there are no comments for that rating.

Template code (this is on a single entry page inside channel:entries):

```
{embed="vendor/.ratings" entry-id="{entry_id}" vendor-type="{categories show_group="10" limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/categories}"}
```

And that embed looks like this (some pieces removed for brevity):

```
{exp:rating:entries precision="2" orderby="rating_date" sort="desc" img_height="14" img_width="14" collection="directory" entry_id="{embed:entry-id}" limit="200"}

{exp:rating:comments
     rating_id="{rating_id}"
     limit="1"
     status="open|closed" 
}
<div class="vendor-reply">
<h5>Reply from {title}</h5>
<h6>{rating_comment_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</h6>
<div class="restrict-height">
{rating_comment}
<div class="overflow"><a href="#">Read more…</a></div>
</div>
</div>
{if rating_comment_no_results}
{if logged_in_member_id == author_id}
{embed="vendor/.rating-reply" rating-id="{rating_id}"}
{/if}
{/if}
{/exp:rating:comments}

{/exp:rating:entries}
```

And then inside that next embed we have:

```
{exp:rating:comment_form
    form:class="review-reply"
    rating_id="{embed:rating-id}"
    return="vendor/rating-reply-thanks/{segment_2}"
    status="closed"
    require_membership="yes" 
    anonymous="no" 
}
    <label>Reply to this review <span class="expl">This option is available only to the listing owner</span></label>
    <textarea class="autosize" placeholder="Write your reply…" name="comment" /></textarea>
    <a class="btn directory submit" href="#">Submit Reply</a>
{/exp:rating:comment_form}
```

With the `{if rating_comment_no_results}` conditional in place, the second embed never shows, even when the conditional is true. If I remove that conditional it shows as expected so there's no problem with the embeds or other code. The conditional simply doesn't work.

Any ideas Solspace?

Comment: Have you tried a hard-coded string in the conditional such as `{if rating_comment_no_results}No results.{/if}` for testing?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{if rating_no_results} ... {/if}`, which is the "no results" conditional used in the other Rating tags. Looks like the "comment" part should be removed in the docs.

Comment: {if rating_no_entries} does not work, however {if rating_no_results} does seem to work. Any possible conflict between rating:comments and rating:entries no_results conditional if one is inside the other and they both use the same conditional tag?

Comment: Sorry! I meant {if rating_no_results} ("_entries" is definitely wrong). Edited the answer above.